# Помогите исправить ошибку. PHP проект

Tags: php

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "mysqli" not found in C:\Users\petrd\Desktop\ordersimple\ordersimple\conn.php:3 Stack trace: #0 C:\Users\petrd\Desktop\ordersimple\ordersimple\header.php(1): include() #1 C:\Users\petrd\Desktop\ordersimple\ordersimple\index.php(2): include('C:\Users\petrd\...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\Users\petrd\Desktop\ordersimple\ordersimple\conn.php on line 3

Подскажите как мне исправить эту ошибку?

Comment: [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Чтобы решить эту проблему, надо всего лишь поискать по тексту ошибки в интернете. Это будет гораздо быстрее, чем скрупулезно добавлять картиночки

Comment: 1) [Не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119/#12120) 2) Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой (**«почему этот код не работает?»**) должны включать желаемое поведение, *конкретную проблему или ошибку* и *минимальный код* для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**.

Comment: не удаляйте мои комментарии!!